# what is the meaning of error "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed" in Django?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

I'm getting error **FOREIGN KEY constraint failed** in django and my database is **SQLite**. I got this error while updating my data from Django admin. I'm not understanding the meaning of this error. Even I haven't used **Foreign Key** field in my model. Please any one can help to resolve this problem

**models.py**

```
    from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import(
    AbstractBaseUser, 
    BaseUserManager
)

now = timezone.now()

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, username, password, email, first_name, last_name,  **extra_fields):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('User must have a username.')
        else:
            username = username.lower()
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('Password required!')
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email required!')
        else:
            email = self.normalize_email(email)

        user = self.model(
            username = username,
            email = email,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            is_active = True
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        #user.save(using = self._db)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_user(self, username, password, email, first_name, last_name,  **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(
            username = username,
            password = password,
            email = email,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            is_active = True,
            **extra_fields
        )

    def create_superuser(self, username, password, email, first_name, last_name,  **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        return self._create_user(
            username = username,
            password = password,
            email = email,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            # is_active = True,
            #is_superuser = True,
            is_active = True,
            **extra_fields,
        )


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin ):

    username = models.CharField(max_length = 28, unique = True)
    email = models.EmailField("Enter E-mail",unique = True)
    first_name = models.CharField("Enter First name", max_length = 25)
    last_name = models.CharField("Enter Last name", max_length = 25)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']


    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_username(self):
        return self.username

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.first_name+ ' '+self.last_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.last_name

    def has_perms(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_lable):
        return True

    @property
    def active(self):
        return self.is_active

    @property
    def superuser(self):
        return self.is_superuser
    @property
    def staff(self):
        return self.is_staff
```

I'm facing this kind of errors.

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 575, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 223, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1557, in change_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 62, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 58, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1451, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 212, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 261, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 239, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/dev/.virtualenv/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 239, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
[15/Aug/2018 19:37:43] "POST /admin/accounts/user/2/change/ HTTP/1.1" 500 135435
```

My migration file.

**0001.initial.py**

```
    from django.db import migrations, models
    import phonenumber_field.modelfields


    class Migration(migrations.Migration):

        initial = True

        dependencies = [
            ('auth', '0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length'),
        ]

        operations = [
            migrations.CreateModel(
                name='User',
                fields=[
                    ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                    ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                    ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                    ('username', models.CharField(max_length=28, unique=True)),
                    ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, verbose_name='Enter E-mail')),
                    ('first_name', models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Enter First name')),
                    ('last_name', models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Enter Last name')),
                    ('phone_number', phonenumber_field.modelfields.PhoneNumberField(max_length=128)),
                    ('created', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                    ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
                    ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                    ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                    ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
                    ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
                ],
                options={
                    'abstract': False,
                },
            ),


]
```

Comment: Hi. Are you attempting to delete a row from one of your models/tables in Django admin section? Can I see your models.py code please.

Comment: I've added my code. Please check it!

Comment: Do you have `AUTH_USER_MODEL` set to you custom user model in `settings.py` ?

Comment: And try changing: `user.save(using = self._db)` to `user.save()`

Comment: I'm still facing the same error. And AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User' in settings.py

Comment: Ok, so how big of a pain would it be to delete your database and start again? Did you create any users before or after you created your custom user? Are you able to provide the full stack error from your terminal as well for me as well.

Comment: I've recreated my database still I'm facing the same problem And I've added my error. Please check it! Can you explain me meaning of this error I have no experience with SQLite.

Comment: You seem to have a random `UserManager` in your code...is this a typo or is this actually in your code?

Comment: Yes, as windup said there's an extraneous `UserManager` in your `_create_user` method, but I don't think that's the issue. You have `object = UserManager()` when I think you want `objects = UserManager()`, objects is plural to get the object manager.

Comment: What is difference in object and objects? I've changed to objects to object. But same problem.

Comment: The default object manager (`models.Manager`) is attached as the `objects` property of any `models.Model` classes. Hence, `User.objects.filter()`. If you want to overwrite the default manager with a custom one (as is the case here), you need to have it be `objects = UserManager` and `UserManager` needs to extend `models.Manager`.

Your indention seems off. You have `def create_user` indented in as an embedded method of `def _create_user`. Also, looks like the methods below `class User` are supposed to be class methods, but they need to be indented twice to be in the `User` class methods.

Comment: Hi, @Furbeenator I've added migration file of my model above.Please check it! That will be useful. I've fixed indention problem in models.py